# How to link 3objects together in uft functional testing

Tags: vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

We have to link 3 objects together in uft to recognize a particular image

```
'if obj1andobj2exist in obj3 then Perform a particular step End if '
```

Comment: It's really unclear what you're trying to achieve here. Please try to follow the guidelines in [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

using the abs_x, abs_y, width and height ROproperties you can define actually 3 rectangles. The problem afterwards boils down to 2 rectangles being inside a third rectangle which using the data above is abs_x and abs_y of rectangles 1 and 2 being bigger or equal then the same coordonates of rectangle 3.

abs_x + width and abs_y + height of rectangles 1 and 2 however must be smaller than the same of rectangle 3.

If you wanna write nice code then implement a small Rectangle class which can be created from a UI Object. We did it in my project. Helps a lot in defining positions to each other. (A Rectangle usually has 2 points, topLeft and bottomRight which you can calculate from the above mentioned 4 properties)